# Error in submitting a pig job to Google Dataproc with properties file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-pig, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm new to Dataproc and trying to submit a pig job to google dataproc via gcloud

```
   gcloud config set project PROJECT

  gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig   --cluster=cluster-workaround   --region=us-east4   --verbosity=debug   --properties-file=gs://bucket/cvr_gcs_one.properties --file=gs://bucket-temp/intellibid-intermediat-cvr.pig
```

with below property file

```
jarLocation=gs://bucket-data-science/emr/jars/pig.jar
pigScriptLocation=gs://bucket-data-science/emr/pigs
logLocation=gs://bucket-data-science/prod/logs
udf_path=gs://bucket-data-science/emr/jars/udfs.jar
csv_dir=gs://bucket-db-dump/prod
currdate=2022-12-13
train_cvr=gs://bucket-temp/{2022-12-09}
output_dir=gs://analytics-bucket/outoout
```

and below is the sample of pig script which is uploaded to GCS

```
 register $udf_path;

 SET default_parallel 300;
 SET pig.exec.mapPartAgg true; -- To remove load on combiner

 SET pig.tmpfilecompression TRUE          -- To make Compression true between 
 MapReduce Job Mainly when using Joins
 SET pig.tmpfilecompression.codec gz     -- To Specify the type of compression between MapReduce Job
 SET mapreduce.map.output.compress TRUE      --To make Compression true between Map and Reduce
 SET mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
 set mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution false
 SET mapreduce.task.timeout 10800000
 set mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress true
 set mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec 
 org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
 SET mapreduce.map.maxattempts 16
 SET mapreduce.reduce.maxattempts 16
 SET mapreduce.job.queuename HIGH_PRIORITY

 define GSUM com.java.udfs.common.javaSUM();
 define get_cvr_key com.java.udfs.common.ALL_CTR_MODEL('$csv_dir', 'variableList.ini')
 define multiple_file_generator com.java.udfs.common.CVR_KEY_GENERATION('$csv_dir','newcampaignToKeyMap')

  train_tmp1 = load '$train_cvr/' using PigStorage('\t','-noschema') as (cookie,AdvID,nviews,ls_dst,ls_src,ls_di,ls_ft,ls_np,tos,nsess,e100_views,e200_views,e300_views,e400_views,e100_tos,e200_tos,e300_tos,e400_tos,uniq_prod,most_seen_prod_freq,uniq_cat,uniq_subcat,search_cnt,click_cnt,cart_cnt,HSDO,os,bwsr,dev,hc_c_v,hc_c_tp,hc_c_up,hc_c_ls,hc_s_v,hc_s_tp,hs_s_up,hc_s_ls,hc_clk_pub,hc_clk_cnt,hc_clk_lm,hp_ls_v,hp_ls_c,hp_ls_s,hp_ms_v,hp_ms_c,hp_ms_s,hu_v,hu_c,hu_s,purchase_flag,hp_ls_cvr,hp_ls_crr,hp_ms_cvr,hp_ms_crr,mpv,gc_c_tp,gc_clk_cnt,gc_c_up,gc_clk_lm,gc_c_v,gc_c_ls,gc_s_v,gc_s_lsts,gc_s_tp,gc_s_up,gc_clk_pub,epoch_ms,gc_ac_s,gc_ac_clk,gc_ac_vclk,udays,hc_vclk_cnt,gc_vclk_cnt,e205_view,e205_tos,AdvID_copy,hc_p_ms_p,hc_c_ms_p,most_seen_cat_freq,hc_p_ls_p,currstage,hc_c_city);
```

Getting below error

```
INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /root/.pigbootup not found
ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext - Undefined parameter : udf_path
2022-12-13 11:58:51,504 [main] 
ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. 
org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParameterSubstitutionException: Undefined parameter : udf_path
```

Tried most of the methods using console as well, doesn't get good documentation to go through.

And Whats Exactly the difference between Query parameters Field(Specify the parameter names and values to insert in place of parameter entries in the query file. The query uses those values when it runs.) and Property Field(A list of key-value pairs to configure the job.
) in UI

Can somone guide me here on what im doing wrong and how can i run a pig script in Dataproc

Comment: Hi @chethi, Can you confirm whether you have registered your jar file or not?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar I'm passing jar info in a variable in properties file and using that variable in pig script to register jar. Am im missing anything .?

Comment: Hi @chethi, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: @ShipraSarkar Already did and following with support team and do you know any good documentatin of dataproc to run hadoop jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it like below ,

```
  gcloud config set project PROJECT

  gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig   --cluster=cluster-workaround   --region=us-east4   --verbosity=debug   --properties-file=gs://bucket/cvr_gcs_one.properties --file=gs://bucket-temp/your_pig.pig --params udf_path=gs://your_udfs.jar
```